# Perl: Assigning References to Array Elements in a Foreach Loop

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, foreach

I really wanted to figure this out myself, but my face is now hurting from continually running into this brick wall.

I'm trying to load 9 text files, each consisting of a matrix of 7 rows of 7 characters seperated by spaces and then save each referenced matrix to an element in an array. I am reading in each file just fine, but when I go to access my array all of the elements are the same. I've been searching for a solution and either my question isn't answered anywhere, or (more likely) I'm not understanding the answer. Here's the problem section of my code:

```
my @boardarray = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
sub LoadBoards {
    my (@board, $infile, @allboards);
    my $i = 1;
    @allboards = @boardarray;
    foreach (@allboards) {
        my $infile = "board" . $i . "\.brd";
        open FILE, "< $infile" or die $!;
        my $line = 0;
        while (<FILE>) {
            chomp $_;
            my @chars = split (/ /,$_);
            $board[$line] = [@chars];
            $line++;
        }
    my $tempboard = \@board;
        DisplayOneBoard($tempboard); print ("\n");              #Test A
    $boardarray[$i-1] = \@board;                                #Problem line?
        DisplayOneBoard($boardarray[$i-1]); print ("\n");       #Test B
        DisplayOneBoard($boardarray[0]); print ("\n----\n");    #Test C
    $i++;
    }
}
```

-I've tried assinging variables as the elements of @boardarray with no change.
-I was using @boardarray in the foreach loop and changed it to the copied @allboards with no improvement.
I expect the 'Test A' and 'Test B' lines to be the same and for the 'Test C' line to stay the first matrix I loaded in. However, all three are the same for every iteration.
(For iteration 1 they are all matrix 1. For iteration 2 they are all matrix 2, etc.)
At the end all the elements are the exact same matrix (matrix 9).

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see you updating `$i` anywhere in this code.

Comment: I do an `$i++` at the very bottom of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are re-using *the same* `@board` each time through your loop. When you push a reference to that board onto `@boardarray`, you are pushing a reference pointing the same `@board` each time. The fix is simple, just move `my @board` to the inside of your `foreach` loop; this creates a new `@board` each time through.

Answer (score 4):

You might have better luck by breaking down the code a bit more and using arrays as stacks with push/pop:

```
sub load_file {
    my ($filename) = @_;
    open my $file, '<', $filename or die $!;
    my @array;
    while (<$file>) {
        chomp $_;
        my @chars = split (/ /,$_);
        push @array, \@chars;    ### adds a reference to the char line 
                                 ### array to the end of the array
    }
    return \@array;              ### return a ref to the 2-d array
}

sub load_files {
    my ($num) = @_;
    my %boards;     ### A hash, so we can refer to loaded arrays
                    ### with a string ID

    for my $filenum ( 1 .. $num ) {
         my $filename = "board" . $filenum . "\.brd";
         $boards{$filenum} = load_file($filename);
    }

    return \%boards;   ### return a ref to the hash of 2-d arrayrefs
}

### use it now...
my $boards = load_files(9); ### load 9 files.

DisplayOneBoard($boards->{6}); ### dereference our hashref, pass board in
                               ### key '6'to be displayed
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to change this line in the first sub: `open FILE, '<', $filename or die $!;` and this line in the second sub: `my $filename = "board" . $filenum . "\.brd";` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks -- I've corrected the code. Re the file open, it's usually best practice to use a lexical filehandle instead of a glob (ie, a scalar) as it can be passed around between subs, and you get some other implicit benefits, such as the filehandle getting closed automatically when it goes out of scope. Thus, `open $file ...` will work when you read with `while (<$file>) ...`. The filenum error was lazy copying tho :)

Comment: I also noticed that this is leaving element 0 empty. A simple change solved that too. `$boards{$filenum-1} = load_file($filename);`

Comment: Good advice on the filehandle. I've made that change as well. The book I tought myself from used the glob, so I've been doing the same.

Comment: It does leave 0 empty, but using `$boards{$filenum-1} = load_file($filename)` means `$boards{'6'}` will contain "board7\.brd"s contents. If you really just want to treat boards as an array, declare it as such, and load it with a `push @boards, load_file($filename)`

Comment: Only because later in my code I position the boards on a grid and it makes it easier to refer to the position array element and the hash key by the same number does this matter to me right now. Though I may change it back later since I'm thinking of randomizing the layout of the boards upon the grid.